# Write combobox selected item to xml file

Tags: xml, vb.net, combobox

I have the following VB.NET code and was expecting the contents of combobox1 to be written to the xml file however it dose nothing?

```
            'Creating XML file first...
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\PROFILE.xml")

        objWriter.WriteLine("<COMPELATION>")
        objWriter.WriteLine("</COMPELATION>")
        objWriter.Close()

        'Writing XML content...
        Dim xmldoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        xmldoc.Load(IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\PROFILE.xml")

        With xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/COMPELATION").CreateNavigator().AppendChild()
            .WriteStartElement("DATA")
            .WriteElementString("PROJECTID", TextBox1.Text)
            .WriteElementString("CLIENTID", ComboBox1.SelectedText)
            .WriteElementString("CDATE", Date.Today)
            .WriteElementString("CTIME", Now.ToShortTimeString)

            .WriteEndElement()
            .Close()
        End With
        xmldoc.Save(IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\PROFILE.xml")

        Dim filepath As String = (IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & "\PROFILE.xml")
        Dim DS_PROJECTS As New DataSet
        DS_PROJECTS.ReadXml(filepath)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComboBox1.SelectedText` represents what is highlighted. Probably there is no highlighted item in blue when your code is executed. Therefore nothing is inserted in `CLIENTID` label.

Use `Combobox1.Text` instead which represents what you've selected.

```
.WriteElementString("CLIENTID", ComboBox1.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified you code hardcoding values from combobox and text box.  I then put results into a DataGridView and it appears to work.

```css
Imports System.Xml
Public Class Form1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILENAME)

        objWriter.WriteLine("<COMPELATION>")
        objWriter.WriteLine("</COMPELATION>")
        objWriter.Close()

        'Writing XML content...
        Dim xmldoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
        xmldoc.Load(FILENAME)

        With xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/COMPELATION").CreateNavigator().AppendChild()
            .WriteStartElement("DATA")
            .WriteElementString("PROJECTID", "abc")
            .WriteElementString("CLIENTID", "def")
            .WriteElementString("CDATE", Date.Today)
            .WriteElementString("CTIME", Now.ToShortTimeString)

            .WriteEndElement()
            .Close()
        End With
        xmldoc.Save(FILENAME)

        Dim filepath As String = (FILENAME)
        Dim DS_PROJECTS As New DataSet
        DS_PROJECTS.ReadXml(filepath)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = DS_PROJECTS.Tables(0)
    End Sub
End Class
​
```